# Loading a html 5 page within iOS app

Tags: ios

We are currently building an iOS app and we need to get it submitted asap, however, one of the features are not quite ready so I am thinking as a temporary measure to put in a button which when clicked opens an external page with a html 5 web page within the app and the user can fill in their data and continue within the app as if they never left.

Obviously there will be some minor difference between the web page and the actual app but the key is we don't want people leaving the app, I just need the html 5 page to load inside the app so the user gets a good experience.

Is this possible and what is the best way to execute this?

Comment: Just use a  WKWebView

Comment: @CriagEdmonds Could you please accept an answer ?